# Post list using jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this code in razor

```
@{
    var aid = new List<int>();
    foreach (var item in Model.applications)
    {
        if (item.Status == 1)
        {
            aid.Add(item.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

and in js I have this:

```
<script>
function checkIfSigned() {

    var data = { aid: @aid };
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")',
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        ...
    });
}
```

and in my controller:

```
public JsonResult Method(List<int> aid)
{
  foreach (var item in aid)
  { ... }
}
```

my problem is:

> var data = { aid: @aid };

It throws an exception:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unterminated template literal
>
> var data = { aid: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] };

What can I do? how can I post list?

Comment: The string representation of an object is just the class name of that object.  You can perhaps JSON-serialize the object when outputting it to the page.  Though why do you need to do this in the first place?  You're sending unmodified data back to the server which just gave you that data.  Seems unnecessary.

Comment: You need to convert your  c# list to a javascript array. But why is that code in your view (it belongs in your controller)

Comment: I know it should be in controller but for now I haven't any other way.. I must check these values using timeout

Comment: Sorry, but what your doing makes not sense (and as @David has noted, its pointless) - but your can use `var data = { aid: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(aid)) };` and the you need `data: JSON.stringify(data);` and `contentType: 'application/json',`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks. and what type of parameter should I pass in action method?

Comment: `List<int> aid` is fine (or `IEnumerable<int> aid`)

Comment: anyway both are null..

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that :

```
var data = []; // javascript array
@foreach(var item in Model.applications)
{
    if (item.Status == 1)
    {
        <text> 
           /* start JS */
           data.push('@item.Id'); 
           /* end JS */
        </text>
    }
}
```

and in JS Ajax :

```
    <script>
    function checkIfSigned() {

        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")',
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            ...
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: just delete this line : var data = { aid: @aid };

Comment: I have `(IEnumerable<string> data)` as parameter but call is not going inside it and logs internal 500 error

Comment: ok it was because of content-type. I remove it and call goes inside method but both `IEnumerable<int> data` or `IEnumerable<string> data` are null..

Comment: Try this :  
`$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")',
            type: "POST",
            data: {aid: data},
            ...
        });`

Comment: I'm trying same

Comment: Both `IEnumerable<int>` or `IEnumerable<string>` are `null` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139981/discussion-between-majdi-saibi-and-gsiradze).